# Visual Studio set one menu strip for multiple forms

Tags: c#, winforms, menubar

I wanted to know if there is a way of setting the same menu strip for multiple forms? Like a "static" menu strip?
Thanks!

Comment: cant you just add it to the other form? **form1.Controls.Add(menuStrip);**, **form2.Controls.Add(menuStrip);** etc

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was solved with just adding the existing menuStrip to other forms via

```
form1.Controls.Add(menuStrip);
form2.Controls.Add(menuStrip);
```