# Winforms assign same menu strip to multiple forms

Tags: powershell, winforms

I'm trying to build a simple-ish winform script,
it basically runs on two forms, of course one is main and launching the other.

So i got myself into creating a menustrip, now, what if i want to add it to both forms?
Answer would seem easy:

```
$form1.Controls.Add($menuStrip);
$form2.Controls.Add($menuStrip);
```

But actually the second line removes the menu from the first form, weird uh?

Getting into details:

```
#After defining first form
$menuStrip             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip
$menuStrip.height      = 25
$menuStrip.autosize    = $false
$form1.Controls.Add($menuStrip)

#After Defining second form
$form2.Controls.Add($menuStrip)

#Boom, first form menu's gone, reduced to atoms.
```

Now slightly out of topic:

```
$form1.MainMenuStrip    = $menuStrip
```

I've seen some people using this string, i tryed removing it / adding it to both forms / only in first and vice versa with no changes, is it even important? i've been banging my head on this for a while.

Comment: It's not weird. Each control can have at most one parent control. Each form will need its own new instance.

Comment: Then i suppose this post made some confusion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463629/visual-studio-set-one-menu-strip-for-multiple-forms

Comment: The answer on that post is incorrect.

Comment: `[Form].MainMenuStrip` is used to define the main MenuStrip container of a Window. It's used because MenuStrips can be merged, as usually happens in a MDI Project, where a Form is defined as the MDIForm Container and child Forms, that may have their own MenuStrip used for local functionalities, merge their MenuStrip with the MainMenuStrip when shown.

Comment: Can you please share the full forms declaration?